# Solve $p,q,r,s,t$ for this set of statements

Tags: inequality

Obtained from the [UKMT IMK Grey 2014 Q21](https://www.ukmt.org.uk/pdfs/2014/GK14.pdf):

Note that I DO NOT want answers; only hints.

> An antique set of scales is not working properly. If something is lighter than 1000g, the scales
>   show the correct weight, otherwise, the scales can show any value greater than 1000g.
>   Jenny grows giant fruit and vegetables. She has a pumpkin, a quince, a radish, a swede and a
>   turnip whose weights are all less than 1000g and, in grammes, are
>   P, Q, R, S and
>   T.
>   When she weighs them in pairs, the scale shows the following:
>   quince and swede: 1200g radish and turnip: 2100g quince and turnip: 800g
>   quince and radish: 900g pumpkin and turnip: 700g. Which of the following lists gives the masses in descending order?

So, in this question, I have obtained:

1) $q+s>1000$

2) $r+t>1000$

3) $q+t = 800$

4) $p+t = 700$

5) $q+r = 900$

I added 4) and 5) to get $p+r+q+t=1600$, which gets taken away from 3) to get:

6) $p+r=800$

Also, 1) + 2) is

7) $q+r+s+t>2000$

I have retrieved these(not necessarily useful) equations/inequalities. I do not know how to get on from here.

Comment: I am not sure if this will be helpful, but perhaps you could introduce two 'excess variables $e_1, e_2$ such that you get an equality in the first two equations. (I have tried this, it gives you a system of linear equations in 7 variables). Requiring that the $e_i > 0$, it narrowed down the ranges on the possible weights.

Comment: In fact, that is a good idea, except that ConMan's idea is better, and less complex. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Some additional things you can use:

1. Subtracting (4) from (3) gives you $r - t = 100$, which you can combine with (2) to get some lower bounds on both $r$ and $t$.
2. Subtracting (5) from (4) gives you $q - p = 100$.
3. You are also given $0 < p, q, r, s, t < 1000$, which you can combine with other information to get tighter bounds (for example, since $q - p = 100$, you can state that $0 < p < 900$ and $100 < q < 1000$).

Answer (score 0):

Equations 6) and 7) seems to be useless (contains less informations than previous equations)

1. Solve the system of equations 3), 4) and 5) - you will obtain the solution depending on parameter $t=\tau$

   > $\begin{cases}t=\tau\\ q=800-\tau \\ p=700-\tau\\ r=100+\tau \end{cases}$
2. From 2) you obtain the lower boundary for $\tau$

   > $\tau > 450$
3. From 1) you obtain another parameter ($s=\sigma$) and it's relation with $\tau$:

   > $\sigma > 200 +\tau$
4. Now it is easy to see two groups of inequalities:

   > $s>200+\tau > 100+\tau=r>\tau=t$ and $q=800-\tau>700-\tau = p$, 
   > so $\,\,s>r>t$ and $q>p$
5. Result of second step compared with the result of step 4. gives us connection between these groups:

   > $t=\tau>450 >350=800-450 >800-\tau =q$

Comment: I specifically said no answers ; only hints. (I really should have said no hidden as well)

Comment: @simplest_mathematics - i've specially made the spoilers hidden, so those, who don't want to see them, don't have to. I've edited the headers to be more precise about what happens in each step without seeing the spoiler.

Comment: Doesn't work whatsoever. I am flagging it for this reason.

Comment: There also was reason for me to put a part of an answer in spoiler tag. What was your reason for displaying the spoilers?

Comment: I did not. They were already appeared.